# Slickgrid losing focus on row click

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

When using the cell selection model and checkboxselectcolum plugin, I am running into an issue with slickgrid.
When clicking on a cell, the focus is getting lost on the grid. I noticed the focus is lost after the invalidateRow statement in slick. `Chebxcolumn.js` file.

Is there any workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your issue but I solved mine which sounds similar by using a custom formatter to handle the checkboxes as opposed to one of the ones provided.

HTH
[Slick Grid 2 grids displayed, losing focus on second grid [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319083/slick-grid-2-grids-displayed-losing-focus-on-second-grid-solved)